# Blending two images and drawing resized image from two UIImageViews

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I have two ImageViews, one called imageView and the other called subView (which is a subview of imageView).

I want to blend the images on these views together, with the user being able to switch the alpha of the blend with a pan. My code works, but right now, the code is slow as we are redrawing the image each time the pan gesture is moved. Is there a faster/more efficient way of doing this?

BONUS Q: I want to allow for my subView image to drawn zoomed in. Currently I've set my subView to be UIViewContentModeCenter, however I can't seem to draw a zoomed in part of my image with this content mode. Is there any way around this?

My drawrect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
float xCenter = self.center.x - self.currentImage1.size.width/2.0;
float yCenter = self.center.y - self.currentImage1.size.height/2.0;

subView.alpha = self.blendAmount;  // Customize the opacity of the top image.

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.currentImage1.size);

CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetBlendMode(c, kCGBlendModeColorBurn);
[imageView.layer renderInContext:c];

self.blendedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[self.blendedImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xCenter,yCenter)];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use GPU for image processing which is far faster than using CPU (as you're doing right now).

You can use [Core Image](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html) framework which is very fast and easy to use but requires iOS 5, or you can use [Open GL](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html) directly but you need to be experienced and have some knowledge about Open GL Shading.

Comment: Thanks - I've tried switching over to using Core Image but now it seems like I have to apply two filters in my drawrect to achieve the same results: CIColorMatrix (to adjust alpha of top image) and then a CIBlendFilter (to add the blend). This makes the whole process slow (if not slower than before!). Do you know if there's any way around this?

Comment: Managed to get round this. Thanks for the tip!